# Error File is not a SQLite 3 database

Tags: android, database, sqlite, ubuntu

I am trying to open a database file of a project on `SQLite` to see file structure for my Android project and as I know that DB file was also made for Android project but getting error `File is not a SQLite 3 database`. I know it means this DB file is made on lower version of SQL but is there any way to open this file on SQLite Database Browser?

Please help.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you extending SQLiteOpenHelper in your application?  Or are you using a 3rd party alternative like android-sqlite-asset-helper (https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-sqlite-asset-helper)?

Answer (score 0):

I saw this when I created a database with a 64k page size, which confuses some sqlite browsers.  This is because the value in the header for this page size is zero instead of the actual value for 64K.